# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I have a tif files from a specific directory, I have a function to read the all the tif files and converted it to text, after the conversion I move it to a folder named "Completed" once it was successfully converted, and move it Failed folder once it was failed to convert. the Problem is the when I used the Move method of System.IO.File it was raised an error saying that

> "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

What is the problem, I closed the file , I dispose it , but still the error occurs?

Comment: I wonder what your code looks like.

Comment: Did you load this into an Image?  If so did you Dispose of that?

Comment: actually I closed it and dispose it also

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you close the file, as well as anything associated with it during the processing.

*(since you chose not to show us code, we don't really know what got created during the processing.)*

Look for things like MemoryStreams, MemoryMapped Files, Images backed by files, File handles stored in a container or IEnumerable, etc.

You have the right idea making sure you explicitly `.Close()` known references, and Dispose of objects, but something is still holding the file.

Comment: I closed the file when the process was done, before moving it the specific directory

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this and the issue was that I wasn't able to delete the original file if I created it using the "FromFile" method of the Image class.  Instead, I created it using the "FromStream" method (making sure to Close and Dispose of it at the end).

I modified my code to work like method #3 here: http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2009/07/process-cannot-access-file-because-it.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your conversion process has completely finished before moving.  Sometimes it looks like a process is done when it really isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close StreamReader, StreamWriter and any other processes that are operating the file before you perform a different operation with it.
e.g. If you are reading with StreamReader and need to write to he file close StreamReader and then start StreamWriter.

Alternatively you could use Filestream and I have heard that in the .NET Framework 4.0 they have introduced asynchronous file operations.