# How do I force delete a folder being used by another process?

Tags: c#, .net, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I delete a file that is in use by another process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232647/how-can-i-delete-a-file-that-is-in-use-by-another-process)

I have the following c# code but it throws an exception on the call to the Delete method:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\mydirectory\");
dir.Delete(true);
```

The following exception is thrown:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\mydirectory' because it is being used by another process.

Is there any way to force it to delete this directory even though it's being used by another process?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232647/how-can-i-delete-a-file-that-is-in-use-by-another-process

Answer (score 10, accepted):

no, not without stopping the other process